# My iPad started showing the mobile version

Tags: support, status-completed, mobile-web, ipad

I was browsing Stack Overflow with my iPad and 15 minutes ago it started showing the mobile version instead of the full one. Clicking on the "full version" link at the bottom of the page does not help as it still shows the mobile version. Is this a permanent change? (hope not)

Comment: Our devs are working on it.

Comment: It's also broken on iPhone as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's just MVC4's built in Mobile views fighting with our homegrown version.  Fix should be coming in a few minutes...

Comment: If you "Clear Cookies and Data" from the Settings app (in the Safari section), it should fix it.  At least, it did for me after the 2nd or 3rd try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed in the build currently rolling out.

Essentially both we and the MVC team came around to the same naming convention for our views, and the implementations co-exist so well together that we didn't catch* you couldn't switch back to the Desktop view from a mobile device.

Fix is, somewhat humorously, to just have MVC4 treat every device as a Desktop and let our existing code handle detecting mobile devices.

<sub>*MVC4 also considers the iPad a mobile device while we don't, but that's a minor detail.</sub>