# iPad showing mobile site on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, ipad

My iPad has started showing the mobile site. Is this just how it is now or can I get the full site back?

Comment: If clicking the "full site" link does not help, it means [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144693/my-ipad-started-showing-the-mobile-version) has returned and it's a dupe of that other report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a **site mode** link on the bottom of page, when you are in **mobile site** mode. Click on it and you will be back to normal full site back.

See the **site mode** in following link,

> [image]

Comment: Derp. Didn't see that. My daughter must have switched it.

Comment: **lovely kids** :)